# Using commands to create a log env for zookeeper

Tags: linux, command-line

Hi guys I'm doing the following commands to create a log when I run zookeeper. However the 2nd command says file not found. Why is this so? Thank you a lot in advance

```
# create a zookeeper-env.sh under the conf folder
$ tee zookeeper-env.sh <<EOF
ZOO_LOG_DIR="\$ZOOBINDIR/../logs"
ZOO_LOG4J_PROP="INFO, ROLLINGFILE"
EOF
# enable log rotation
$ sed -i \
-e
's/#log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex/log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBack
upIndex/' \
log4j.properties
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the file structure? This would help a lot.